# sqlite3 python 2.7 how to enable more detailed error reporting (exceptions) from sqlite3?

Tags: python-2.7, exception, error-handling, sqlite

I am trying to insert multiple rows with the `executemany` function. My complete code is given at the end.

The exception I get is

```
sqlite3.IntegrityError: column carname is not unique
```

I wish I could a more detailed error report giving the offending values that caused the error. Is it possible to get a more detailed error report (in an exception) from `sqlite3` so that it gives back the offending values that caused the error?
For example, in my code, the following values are offending:

```
(0, 'Audi', 52642),
(1, 'Audi', 52642),
```

The `carname` should be unique.

Or do I have to insert the values one-by-one only and observe the exceptions?

My code: based on [this tutorial](http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitepythontutorial/), I have added the `UNIQUE` constraint on the column carname.

```
import sqlite3 as lite
import sys

cars = (
    (0, 'Audi', 52642),
    (1, 'Audi', 52642),
    (2, 'Mercedes', 57127),
    (3, 'Skoda', 9000),
    (4, 'Volvo', 29000),
    (5, 'Bentley', 350000),
    (6, 'Hummer', 41400),
    (7, 'Volkswagen', 21600)
)

tblstr = """CREATE TABLE cars (
  carid integer PRIMARY KEY,
  carname NVARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,
  price integer NOT NULL
);"""


con = lite.connect('test.db')

with con:

    cur = con.cursor()    

    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Cars")
    cur.execute(tblstr)
    cur.executemany("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(?, ?, ?)", cars)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that since you have placed a unique constraint on one of the column names, unless you have pre-vetted the data you should not be using `executemany`.
Instead, use a `for ... loop` to loop over the data and use an `execute` within a `try .. except` statement for each update.
This allows you to list any errors and yet continue.
For example:

```
with con:

    cur = con.cursor()

    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Cars")
    cur.execute(tblstr)
    for x in cars:
        try:
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars(carid,carname,price) VALUES(?, ?, ?)",(x[0],x[1],x[2]))
        except Exception as err:
            print err, x
```